# Mongoose, Matching a field of string array type with a given string array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Suppose there is a Schema and there is a field

```
 phoneNumber:{
    type:[String],
    required:true
},
```

now i want to compare this column with an array , example `["ABC","DEF"]`. How can i check if any element in this array matches with an element in a document

```
Like if there are documents A =  { phoneNumber :["ACD, "BFG"]} and B= {phoneNumber:["GCD"]}
```

The query should return the B document if i check using `C= ["GCD"]`, as B is the only document that contains "GCD" element.
I did try to use `myDoc.find({phoneNumber:{$in:["GCD"]})` but it isnt returning anything. What is the correct query which is to be used

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Please format your post and clearly show each document separately and data in each document.

Answer (score 2):

Use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

```
db.collection.find({"phoneNumber.type": { $in: ["ACD", "BFG"] } })
```